# Is there a value of maxdelay for which repaint(long maxdelay) = repaint()?

Tags: java, awt, repaint

In `repaint(long maxDelay)` (from `java.awt.Component`), `maxDelay` specifies the maximum number of milliseconds that can elapse before `update` is called.

Does plain `repaint()` have such a maximum? If it doesn't have a maximum, does this mean an arbitrary length of time can pass before update() is called? If it has a maximum, what is it?

Comment: What API are you talking about?  To what object does this `repaint` method belong too?  You'll need to provide additional context to your question to help us out

Comment: I'm talking about the `repaint` method of `java.awt.Component`.

Comment: Having dug through the code some, it would appear that `tm` is ignored :/. Even the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(long,int,int,int,int)) suggest so, *"tm - this parameter is not used"*

Comment: @MadProgrammer that link is for `JComponent`, not for plain `Component`.

Comment: No, it’s not, but it’s a good hint, of course you could just look at the source and you’d know that the value is ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter maxDelay is usually ignored, both in AWT and Swing. 
Judging from the source code of JDK 1.8:

AWT, parameter tm unused:

```
public void repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
...
         PaintEvent e = new PaintEvent(this, PaintEvent.UPDATE,
                                          new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
         SunToolkit.postEvent(SunToolkit.targetToAppContext(this), e);
     }
}
```

Swing, parameter tm unused:

```
public void repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    RepaintManager.currentManager(SunToolkit.targetToAppContext(this))
                  .addDirtyRegion(this, x, y, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I assume it's the same for JDK 10?

Comment: One commenter remarked that JavaDoc says ""tm - this parameter is not used", so I guess all versions that have this spec should also ignore it. Although you might have custom subclass others framework subclass, that might change the behaviour. A corresponding graphic subsystem would need to have more advanced invalidation regions.